# Clan rat shields in skirmish

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

Me and a friend have just started Aos  skirmishes. Skaven have the below rule for Shields:

[image]

But in skirmish units are single models. How should this rule work?

We currently give the +1 save for each model that has a shield no matter the count of other models on the field. It seems fair as rats are so squishy, but are we doing the correct thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Competitive/Matched Play answer.

No. They shouldn't get the save, since each individual unit is a single model.

### Narrativist/Open Play Answer.

Yes. If it makes your game more fun, and everyone agrees, change things however you all like. It's your game do what you want even if it's not technically correct.